# How to ensure a thread starts right after calling thread.start() - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
        int n = 10;
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread odd = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i+=2) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("odd " + i);
                    lock.notify();
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Thread even = new Thread(() -> {
               //bookmark line
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("even " + i);
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        });
        even.start();
        odd.start();
```

this programs just works fine and print even and odd alternatively. But the question i have is because of **thread scheduler**, there is a possibility that my **odd** thread start before **even** thread. how do i ensure that even thread always start right before odd thread ?

Comment: Latches, semaphores, starting the odd thread inside the even thread... take your pick.

Comment: you can make 1 thread wait for some code to execute in the other, by using wait/notify

Comment: Starting odd thread inside the even thread will be easiest way for me. Thanks @Joe C

Comment: @SargeBorsch: you could, true.  But, why use what amounts to "concurrency assembly language" to achieve something that could be more concisely and more readably achieved using the higher level facilities in the concurrent library?

Comment: @scottb knowing the primitives is important as well.

Answer (score -1):

cheap solution is sleep odd thread 500 mills at the beginning before for loop

Comment: How do you calculate 500 mills ?

Comment: Thread odd = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i+=2) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("odd " + i);
                    lock.notify();
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

Comment: The OP is trying to complete a homework assignment, and the assignment probably is meant to teach him/her how to _guarantee_ correct behavior.   Using sleep() in the way that you suggest makes it extremely likely that the program will behave correctly, but it does not guarantee correct behavior.

Comment: how is that cheap?

Answer (score -1):

Put 'odd.start();' inside the even thread